# Composição de item da mesma tabela SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, lógica, table, mysql

Bom, comecei a estudar recentemente MySQL e encontrei uma dúvida na qual não consegui resolver:
Uma tabela ITEM possui as colunas (PK)cd_item, nm_item, ds_item, cd_tipo_item, o problema no caso é que um item pode ser formado pela composição de 2 ou 3 itens ou simplesmente ser único (não é composto por nada), o objetivo disso é selecionar do banco o item e sua receita (composição feita), porém não sei como resolver isso, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que fazer algo parecido, fiz da seguinte maneira:
Tenho uma tabela `produto`, onde estão armazenadas todas as informações do produto, essas são apenas informações fake.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produto` (
  `produto_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `quantidade` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`produto_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Aqui temos uma tabela de `composicao` onde teremos referência com a tabela `produto` 2 vezes onde `produto_id` será o id do produto principal e `materia_id`receberá o id do produto que forma sua composição.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `composicao` (
  `composicao_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `produto_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `materia_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`composicao_id`),
  INDEX `fk_composicao_produto_idx` (`produto_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_composicao_produto1_idx` (`materia_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_composicao_produto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`produto_id`)
    REFERENCES `forum`.`produto` (`produto_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_composicao_produto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`materia_id`)
    REFERENCES `produto` (`produto_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Nesse `INSERT` irei dar exemplo de 4 produtos, 3 que não possuem composição(Madeira,Parafuso e Prego) e um que vai ter composição que é o Carrinho de madeira.

```
INSERT INTO produto(descricao, quantidade) VALUES('Madeira', 1),('Parafuso', 1),('Prego',1),('Carrinho de Madeira', 1);
```

Aqui iremos inserir a composicao do carrinho de madeira(Madeira e Prego)

```
INSERT INTO composicao(produto_id, materia_id) VALUES(4,1),(4,3);
```

E por fim a `query` dos produtos.

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pc.descricao SEPARATOR ',') AS composicao
FROM produto p
LEFT JOIN composicao c
ON p.produto_id = c.produto_id
LEFT JOIN produto pc
ON pc.produto_id = c.materia_id
GROUP BY p.produto_id;
```

Tendo como resultado o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vlw, ajudou muito, consegui aqui. MUITO OBRIGADO :D